# Display multiple charts at a time.(Anylogic)

Tags: scroll, anylogic, gantt-chart

I have made a simulation consisting of multiple vehicle agents (about 17), but I can't figure out a way of how I can display time color charts related to each of those vehicles in the main agent. If possible I want it to be in a scroll view so that the user can scroll through the different time color charts. I want to make it sort of like a Gantt chart.

Sort of something like this

[The image related to my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxl48.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrolling is impossible with current AnyLogic UI, unfortunately. You can, however, add buttons to manually "scroll up/down" and change what view area the user sees.

Re plotting itself, either create 17 charts manually and link them to the individual agents.

Or better, create 1 chart in the agent type, have the agent population embedded in Main and adjust the y-component of the chart presentation according to the agent index, something like `100 + (index*15)`

Some example models use this approach so check if you find something similar there